# Adsense image ads only unit is displaying image and text ads

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Adsense 'image ads only' unit displaying image and text ads on my website. I have double checked to make sure that the adsense unit format is set to 'image ads only'.

Have anyone else has experienced this and how did you resolve this issue?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3):

Google use many servers and it takes time for the changes in settings to propogate. Please wait at least 24 hours and see if it stays this way.